# Shared columns of document set not set in Document Information Panel

Tags: document-set, document-info-panel, metadata

After I upload a document in a document set, the edit form is being displayed and all of our shared columns of the document set are set by default as metadata of the document.

When we start with a new document, the shared columns of the document set are being displayed - but does not contain any values.

Does anyone have experience with this behavior?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shared fields are set by an itemeventreceiver, so won't be filled till the document is actually added and saved to the document set.

Comment: Thanks Colin! It's quite annoying for end users because they have to fill in those fields manually - since some of them are required. Nothing we can do about it probably?

Comment: No, not really. Not without some serious coding anyway :-S

Comment: P.S. If this answer satisfies your question, could you mark it as answer?